# RDD of Tuple and RDD of Row differences

Tags: apache-spark

I have two different RDDs and apply a foreach on both of them and note a difference that I cannot resolve.

First one:

```
val data = Array(("CORN",6), ("WHEAT",3),("CORN",4),("SOYA",4),("CORN",1),("PALM",2),("BEANS",9),("MAIZE",8),("WHEAT",2),("PALM",10))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data,3) // NOT sorted

rdd.foreach{ x => {      
             println (x)
                  }}

rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[103] at parallelize at command-325897530726166:8
```

Works fine in this sense.

Second one:

```
rddX.foreach{ x => {      
              val prod = x(0)
              val vol = x(1)
              val prt = counter
              val cnt = counter * 100
              println(prt,cnt,prod,vol)
                   }}

 rddX: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[128] at rdd at command-686855653277634:51
```

Works fine.

Question: why can I not do **val prod = x(0)** as in the second case on the first example? And how could I do that with the foreach? Or would we need to use map for the first case always? Due to Row internals on the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the difference in datatypes

First one is `RDD[(String, Int)]` 
This is an `RDD` of `Tuple2` which contains `(String, Int)` so you can access this as `val prod = x._1` for first value as `String` and `x._2` for second `Integer` value.

Since it is a Tuple you can't access as `val prod = x(0)`

and second one is `RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` which can be access a 
`val prod = x.getString(0)` or `val prod = x(0)`

I hope this helped!